# Denormalization table - SQL Select (Pivot Table?)

Tags: sql

CAMPAIGN table

| ID | campaign_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Campaign A |
| 2 | Campaign B |

PARTICIPANT table

| ID | campaign_id | participant_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Alice |
| 2 | 1 | Ben |

CUSTOM_FIELD table

| ID | campaign_id | field_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Gender |
| 2 | 1 | Age |

FIELD_ANSWER table

| ID | participant_id | field_id | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Female |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 24 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | Male |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 28 |

**With these tables in above, can we query a result as shown below?**

| Campaign Name | Participant Name | Gender | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign A | Alice | Female | 24 |
| Campaign A | Ben | Male | 28 |

Comment: Yes, we can! What have you tried so far? And pleas tag `DBMS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pivoting logic we can try:

```sql
SELECT
    c.campaign_name,
    p.participant_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cf.field_name = 'Gender' THEN fa.answer END) AS Gender,
    MAX(CASE WHEN cf.field_name = 'Age'    THEN fa.answer END) AS Age
FROM CAMPAIGN c
INNER JOIN PARTICIPANT p
    ON p.campaign_id = c.ID
INNER JOIN FIELD_ANSWER fa
    ON fa.participant_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN CUSTOM_FIELD cf
    ON cf.ID = fa.field_id AND cf.campaign_id = c.ID
GROUP BY
    c.campaign_name,
    p.participant_name;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1b4747d5e70a98f89422e3132152ccf) in SQL Server, though the above query should run on most other database as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If the cf.field_name is dynamic which it is not fixed, I should at least query SELECT field_name FROM CUSTOM_FIELD WHERE campaign_id = 1 first, am I right?

Comment: Not really.  My answer works completely fine with the data you posted.  If it _doesn't_ meet some requirement, then edit your question.

Comment: Yes, your answer works completely fine, highly appreciated! I am just wondering if we could make it in one query if the cf.field_name is dynamic, but it's ok I am very happy with your answer already ;)